# necesito incrementar y guardar una valor que obtengo de un edittext en android studio

Tags: php, android

**Codig (JAVA)  para incrementar el  valor Existencia en mi base de  datos**
En esta  parte donde  quiero incrementar  el valor de Existencia  y guardar  su actualización es  donde  tengo  el error.

El  LogCat  me  muestra  el error  aquí.etExistencia.setText(count);

```
 private void submitForm() {
    count= Integer.parseInt(etExistencia.getText().toString());
    count++;
    etExistencia.setText(count);

    UpdateExistencia(
            etNumeroParte.getText().toString(),
            etExistencia.getText().toString()
    );
}

private void UpdateExistencia(final String NumeroParte, final String Existencia) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";
    showLoadingDialog("Por  Favor espere....Actualizando ....");

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_UPDATE_CONTADOR_EXISTENCIA_PROD, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado = jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Toast toast1= Toast.makeText(Movimiento.this,"Actualización correcta",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast1.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast1.show();
                } else {
                    hideLoadingDialog();

                    Toast toast2= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No existe  Número de Parte  con este ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast2.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("NumeroParte",NumeroParte);
            params.put("Existencia",Existencia);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}


public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
    try {
        if (loading == null) {
            loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        loading.setIndeterminate(true);
        loading.setCancelable(false);
        loading.setMessage(texto);
        loading.show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        loading = null;
    }
}

public void hideLoadingDialog() {
    try {
        if (loading != null) {
            loading.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception a) {
        loading = null;
    }
}
```

**EL ERROR QUE ME  MUESTRA AL EJECUTAR  MI PROYECTOR ES EN ESTA  PARTE**

etExistencia.setText(count);

**Este es el error que me arroja el LogCat.**

> 01-23 22:45:33.157 9939-9939/com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql, PID: 9939
>                                                                                       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   0x1
>                                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
>                                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.Movimiento.submitForm(Movimiento.java:213)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.Movimiento.access$100(Movimiento.java:34)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.example.aceraspire.fujitsu_mysql.Movimiento$2.onKey(Movimiento.java:93)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9876)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1667)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:403)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1800)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3021)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:317)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4327)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4298)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)

Comment: Hola, puedes compartir la excepción que te arroja?

Comment: @Carlos Cardoso, acabo de  agregar  el error que me  muestra el LogCat

Comment: Te da el error porque a setText le tienes que pasars un string, no un entero. Se lo puedes pasar como etExistencia.setText(count+"");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es:

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1 at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)

Debes convertir el valor que deseas utilizar a String ya que si usas un entero el sistema tratará de buscar un recurso en tu aplicación:

```
 etExistencia.setText(count); //* INCORRECTO!
```

**convierte a `String` el valor de `count`,** ejemplo:

```
etExistencia.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

o de otra forma:

```
etExistencia.setText(""+count);
```